# Matching regexp with boundary values in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to match below mentioned regexp with `\b` and `\W`. It doesn't match with `\b` but matches with `\W`

```
my $response = "ABC-12-1-1::HELLO=TX,PROVFEADDR=\"\",ValueFORM=NAME-CITY-STREET-PRT,";

print "\n\n\n$response\n\n\n";
if ( $response =~ /PROVFEADDR=\b/ )    ##### matching with //PROVFEADDR=\W/
{
    print "matched\n";
} else {
    print "not matched\n";
}
```

Any clues

As per the user comments I am editing post a little.

I understood now why it is matching with `\W`. Below is the problem why i started using `\b`

`PROVFEADDR` is a variable to match. In this particular case I have to match `PROVFEADR=`. Earlier we were using `\W+` instead of `\b`.  With `\W+`, problem is when we have to match at the end of string. `\W+` expects atleast one `\W` which is not there if it is at the last of the string. So I replaced with `\b` which worked in the above mentioned scenario. Any suggestion which can handle both cases?

Comment: You mean it doesn't match with `\b`, but matches with `\W`, right?

Comment: @YuHao: Yes it doesn't match with \b

Comment: Assuming Yu Hao is correct and you meant it the other way around: `\b` is word boundary: The characters to its left and right must be one word character, and one non-word character. `=` and `"` are both non-word, so therefore `\b` fails to match.

Comment: I don't see why you have to match *anything* after `PROVFEADDR=` (although you almost certainly need to match a word-boundary *before* it if it is an identifier). Won't `/\bPROVFEADDR=/` do? or even just `/\bPROVFEADDR\b/`, but you haven't explained properly what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `\b` does not match is that it needs a word and a non-word character next to it, and you have two non-word characters.

In your comments, you have mentioned that you are looking for a replacement for `\W` that also matches end of line, in which case a negative lookahead assertion can be used:

```
if($response =~ /PROVFEADDR=(?!\w)/)
```

It asserts that the next character is not an alphanumeric character. Which will also match end of line (the empty string).

Answer (score 1):

In `$response`, the character after `PROVFEADDR=` is the double quote, not a word, so it matches `\W`(non-word).

It doesn't match `\b` because it's not a word boundary. Compare it with:

```
if($response =~ /PROVFEADDR\b=/)
```

Here, between `R` and `=` is a word boundary.

Comment: A better demonstration would perhaps be `/\bPROVFEADDR=/`, which would prevent partial matches: A common use of `\b`.

Comment: `PROVFEADDR` is a variable to match. In this particular case I have to match `PROVFEADR=`. Earlier we were using `\W+` instead of `\b`.  With `\W+`, problem is when we have to match at the end of string. `\W+` expects atleast one `\W` which is not there if it is at the last of the string. So I replaced with `\b` which worked in the above mentioned scenario. Any suggestion which can handle both cases?

Comment: @Nitesh Use a negative lookahead assertion: `(?!\w)`. It will also match end of line. (Note that I used `\w` and not `\W`)